# Visual C# crawling through a txt file and flagging an error when value is missing

Tags: c#

I have a txt file loaded in visual C#, lets say, for example, the text file is written like this:

"""""

1

2

3

4

5

"""""

it is counting correctly from 1-5.

now lets say I add a txt file that looks like this:

"""""

1

2

3

5

"""""

The 4 is missing from the list. Now I want an error message to popup that says, "Line 4 missing value '4'".. Or something like that. I am new to programming, and I am not expecting anyone to do my work for me, I just need a little bit of guidance as to what steps I can take and I would appreciate any help.

My txt file is being loaded into a richtextbox in VB, it displays as Plain Text.

```
string filename = filedialog.FileName;
textbox1.Text = filedialog.fileName;
richTextBox1.LoadFile(textbox1.Text,
richtextboxStreamType.PlainText
```

Comment: Being a bit more specific with your requirements would be helpful, e.g. is the line order important? i.e. could 5 appear on line 1 and 4 on line 2 and so on? etc Did you mean to post this on DoMyHomework4Me.com ? Do a for loop and inside read the text file line of the for loop counter number, simples.

Comment: where is ur code for read file ?

Comment: You say *"it is counting correctly from 1-5."* So why haven't you shown this code?

Comment: So you are looking for numerical gaps, does the whole text-file contain only contain these numbers or is there text behind it?

Comment: Paul, the line order does matter. 1 has to be on line 1, And I did say that I do not expect any one to do my work for me, I just need a bit of guidance. Do not give me code, all I need is some reference.

Comment: Tim, the text file contains text before the numbers. The file is a log of information that I use to count traffic with a loop, each time a car drives over the loop it inserts a string into the file with the weight, axel length and speed, as well as a general Auto increment decimal that will, in the end, give me the total amount of cars that drive over the loop. these numbers reach up to 50 000 per day. and if there is a number that has been missed, I have to know. I am doing as much research as possible, but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all lines contain only numbers (apart from the `""` at the beginning/end):

```
var numbers = File.ReadLines(path)
.Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && line.Trim().All(Char.IsDigit))
.Select(line => int.Parse(line))
.OrderBy(i => i)
.ToList();
int min = numbers.Min();
int max = numbers.Max();
var gaps = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1).Except(numbers);
if(gaps.Any())
{
    int firstGap = gaps.First();  // 4
    string allGaps = string.Join(",", gaps); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will Try this out and report back.